# Как в Google Chrome посмотреть какой скрипт отработал?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

При нажатии на элемент хочу посмотреть какой скрипт (участок скрипта, функция) отработал.

Как это можно сделать в Google Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

В итоге просто использовал фаерфокс там сразу из коробки в инспекторе прямо можно посмотреть какой на элемент скрипт повешен.

Comment: а Chrome DevTools не подошел ?